# Error expected identifier before '(' token in c

Tags: c

#### About

It's a program to calculate the actual age of a person with years, months and days.

I keep getting an error, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int dia,mes,anio;
int dia_n,mes_n, anio_n;
int edad_a,edad_m, edad_d;

printf("********Ingrese la fecha actual********\nDia:");
scanf("%d",&dia);
printf("Mes:");
scanf("%d", &mes);
printf("Anio:");
scanf("%d", &anio);

printf("********Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento********\nDia:");
scanf("%d",&dia_n);
printf("Mes:");
scanf("%d", &mes_n);
printf("Anio:");
scanf("%d", &anio_n);


if (dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) &&                 (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n){
edad_d=(dia - dia_n) +30;
}
else
if (dia>dia_n) || (dia_n==dia) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes_n>mes) ||     (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n){
edad_d=dia-dia_n;
}

if (dia>dia_n) || (dia==dia_n) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) &&     (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n) {
edad_m=mes-mes_n;
}
else
if (dia_n>dia)&&(mes_n>mes) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n){
edad_m=(mes-mes_n) +11;
}
else
if (dia==dia_n) || (dia>dia_n) && (mes_n>mes) && (anio>anio_n){
edad_m=(mes-mes_n)+12;
}
else
if (dia_n>dia) && (mes>mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n) {
edad_m=(mes-mes_n) -1;
}
if (dia>dia_n) || (dia==dia_n) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) &&     (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n) {
edad_a=anio-anio_n;}
else
if (dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) &&     (anio>anio_n){
edad_a=(anio-anio_n)-1;
}

printf("********Su edad actual es********\n%d anios %d meses y %d dias",     edad_a, edad_m, edad_d);

return 0;
}
```

#### Error:

> 22    19  C:\Users\Briansucho\Desktop\Sin Nombre2.c
>     **[Error] expected identifier before '(' token**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is your first `if` statement. Your code states:

`if (dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n){`

This wrong because all those conditions need to be covered in a final `()`. What I mean is this:

`if ((dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n)){`

> You just required more **`()`**. That is why you are getting that error. Also, your code isn't clean and has a lot of error. I know I should do this, but here is your code all cleaned up error free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int dia,mes,anio;
int dia_n,mes_n, anio_n;
int edad_a,edad_m, edad_d;

printf("********Ingrese la fecha actual********\nDia:");
scanf("%d",&dia);
printf("Mes:");
scanf("%d", &mes);
printf("Anio:");
scanf("%d", &anio);

printf("********Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento********\nDia:");
scanf("%d",&dia_n);
printf("Mes:");
scanf("%d", &mes_n);
printf("Anio:");
scanf("%d", &anio_n);


if ((dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio == anio_n)){
  edad_d=(dia - dia_n) +30;
}
else if ((dia>dia_n) || (dia_n==dia) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes_n>mes) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n)){
  edad_d=dia-dia_n;
}

if ((dia>dia_n) || (dia==dia_n) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n)) {
  edad_m=mes-mes_n;
}
else if ((dia_n>dia)&&(mes_n>mes) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n)){
  edad_m=(mes-mes_n) +11;
}
else if ((dia==dia_n) || (dia>dia_n) && (mes_n>mes) && (anio>anio_n)){
  edad_m=(mes-mes_n)+12;
}
else if ((dia_n>dia) && (mes>mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n)) {
  edad_m=(mes-mes_n) -1;
}
if ((dia>dia_n) || (dia==dia_n) && (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n) || (anio==anio_n)) {
  edad_a=anio-anio_n;}
else if ((dia_n>dia) && (mes_n>mes) || (mes>mes_n) || (mes==mes_n) && (anio>anio_n)){
  edad_a=(anio-anio_n)-1;
}

printf("********Su edad actual es********\n%d anios %d meses y %d dias",     edad_a, edad_m, edad_d);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: But even if you do that, you will get another error.

Comment: You should that to all your `if/else` statement.